# How do i rotate x labels or y labels? (hvplot or holoviews)

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

I've created the following plot with hvplot and want to rotate the xlabels in this plot:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import hvplot.pandas
import holoviews as hv

my_plot = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=[50, 2])).hvplot()
```

[image: rotate xlabel hvplot question]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be done in 2 ways:

**1)** By adding it as argument of .hvplot(**rot=90**)

```
my_plot = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=[50, 2])).hvplot(rot=90)
```

**2)** By using **.opts(xrotation=90)**, if you would like to rotate the labels by 90 degrees. 
For y labels you can use option **yrotation=90**.

```
my_plot = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=[50, 2])).hvplot()
my_plot.opts(xrotation=90)
```

[image: hvplot xlabels rotated 90 degrees]